# flutter FutureBuilder with nullable values

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got a FutureBuilder inside my flutter app which should fetch data that might be null.

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: model.fetchIsCheckedInAsync(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
```

This loads a model from the backend if some parameters match, but if not, it returns null.

Now the problem i am facing is, if the backend returns statuscode 204 and null as data,

```
snapshot.hasData
```

always is false because the implementation of this property is:

```
bool get hasData => data != null;
```

So how do I enter the hasData part even when the data is null? And if this is not good practice, what would be the better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch the connection state of the snapshot. The future builder keeps track of "what's going on" trough this state. When the connection state is done you know that your future has ended. Look at the snippet:

```
switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.none:
        return Text('Press button to start.');
      case ConnectionState.active:
      case ConnectionState.waiting:
        return Text('Awaiting result...');
      case ConnectionState.done:
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        return Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}');
    }
    return null; // unreachable
  },
```